# How to make android app work on specific devices only?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that should work on specific predefined devices only.
The devices need to be identified using some unique id like serial number or iemi.
But starting android 10 these uids are no longer accessible except by system apps.
Is there any way to identify the devices?
I know about android id but it is not persistent and can be changed by root.

I tried to get the serial number and iemibut got exceptions

Comment: Have you read this answer to: [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093659/295004) You should clarify what you mean by 'specific predefined devices' as the general assumption is for consumer hardware which brings up privacy issues and not allowing the customer to install an app on a new device.

Comment: First you can check all hardware properties in your app if you are on the correct device. Using play integrity API and a server you could make the app only start if the server has correctly verified then device integrity and the device type. If you let it require `MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY` then even a rooted device can not fake it. The 10 devices what is so special about them, the hardware the owner or what? Can you control the app installation? Find something else to bind to.

Comment: Hello @MorrisonChangWhat I mean with predefined devices, is that I want the app to work on only 5 or 6 specific devices (not models) and if it is installed on any other devices it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Robert Yes the special about the devices is the owner.